# Graph edit on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a JSON file with data from one of our servers, the x axis starts from 0 nm but I need only the data from 400 - 800 nm. I tried to set the ticks to start from 400, however it did not cut the graph.
`plt.xticks(np.arange(400, 850, step=50))`
Do you have any idea how to make the graph start from 400 nm without modifying the data.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijHiC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
ax=plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim(400,800)
```

to change the limits of the plot